# Database.Batchable List Record Id

Tags: apex, batch, id, contains

I can't get this for loop to work:

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> accounts){
    List<Account> acctsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    List<Contact> allContacts = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact];
    List<Interaction__c> allInteractions = [SELECT *fields* FROM Interaction__c];

    List<Interaction__c> relInterations = new List<Interaction__c>();for(Account act : accounts){
        for(Interaction__c relInt : allInteractions) {
            if((ID)relInt.AccountID__c = act.Id){
```

I get the error

> Expression cannot be assigned

If I remove the (ID) I get

> Condition expression must be of type Boolean: Id

How can I solve this problem? Could it be because I am using Database.Batchable and the list accounts is void? I don't totally understand the void vs static in this case.

As an aside, I tried act.contains(relInt.AccountID__c) and it says that method does not exist, which [seems to be the opposite of what the documentation says](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_contains), right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace = with ==, single equals is for assignment and double for comparison.

Comment: @Chance You need to be careful with that syntax, too, because it can cause subtle bugs when you least expect it: `Boolean someFlag; if(someFlag = true) {...}` will compile, and always execute. It's a nice-to-have, so I understand why it's not forbidden by the syntax. Just be aware of this feature and you'll be fine.